# Creating structs and unions on MPI

Tags: c, struct, mpi, unions

EDITED:
Thanks for the previous assistance. I really appreciate it.

Should i remove the pointer from *list too?
In order to create atributo and estrucura i'm using pointers too, will it be a problem too?

```
union atributo{
    int valor1;
    char valor2[tamChar];  
float valor3;
};


struct estructura{
int tipo[tamEstruct]; //Here i will have an array with the types of the union 
union atributo *list[tamEstruct];

};

union atributo *atributos;  
struct estructura *estructuras;

estructuras = malloc (sizeof(struct estructura) * (cantEstruct) );



MPI_Datatype atributo_MPI;
MPI_Datatype type[1] = { MPI_BYTE };
int blocklen[1] = { tamChar };   // the largest element is the chat
MPI_Aint disp[1];

disp[0]= atributos[0];   // the begin of the union



MPI_Datatype estructura_MPI;
MPI_Datatype type[2] = { MPI_INT, atributo_MPI };
int blocklen[2] = { tamEstruct, tamEstruct};
MPI_Aint disp2[2];

disp2[0]= offsetof(atributos, tipo);
disp2[1]= offsetof(atributos, list);
```

Am i getting close the correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several things wrong in that bit of code.

First, structs and unions are very different in this context. A struct contains each of its elements listed, lined up one after another in memory. A union, on the other hand, is only as large as its largest element, and all of its members share the same memory space (*as if* they were the sole members of a struct). This means you can't pack a union into an `MPI_Struct`, since every member's offset is in fact 0.

There's two ways to tackle the problem of an array of unions:

- Send them as an array of `MPI_BYTE`. This is simple, but risks data corruption if your processes don't share the same data representation (e.g. their integers differ in endianness).
- Use `MPI_Pack()` to pack the values one by one. This is type safe, but more complicated, and it will result in an in-memory copy of your data.

Note that in either case, the receiving process will need to know what values it received (i.e. if it received 3 unions, are those 3 integers, or 2 integers and a float, etc). You'll have to send this information as well if you use unions.

You might want to consider a trickier approach: group the enums according to which of their value is valid, and send a message in which similar enums are placed next to each other (e.g. a message that contains an array of `MPI_INT`s, then an array of `MPI_FLOAT`s and so on). With clever use of derived MPI datatypes, you can preserve type safety, avoid in-memory copying, **and** avoid sending several messages.

---

Second: **NEVER, ever send pointers between MPI processes!** It's easy to think of a `char*` as an array of `char`s, but it really isn't. It's just a memory address that won't make sense to the process you send it to, and even if it did, you didn't actually send the data that it was pointing to. If `valor2` is a string with a reasonably short maximum length, I'd recommend declaring it as `char valor2[maxLength]` so that memory for it is allocated inside the actual struct/union. If that is not feasible, you'll have to do even more memory juggling to get your strings across to the other processes, as you would with any variable sized array.

Comment: i edited the problem. It is better? what should i improve now? Thank you.