# creating mpi derived data type, containing struct with pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, mpi

I have a struct that is defined something like that:

```
typedef struct NodeItem {
int* data;
int info1;
int info2;
struct NodeItem* next;
} *Node;
```

I need to send this struct to another MPI process.
I know that I should use MPI_INT for info1 and info2 when defining the derived data type.
However, I struggle to define a derived data type with my pointers.
"data" points to an array of integers, and its size is only known at runtime.
"next" points to the next item in my linked list.

How should I define my derived data type if my struct contains pointers?
Thanks in advance,
Dvir.

Answer (score 0):

To quote myself from [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19641945/143642):

> **NEVER, ever send pointers between MPI processes!** It's easy to think of a `char*` as an array of `char`s, but it really isn't. It's
>   just a memory address that won't make sense to the process you send it
>   to, and even if it did, you didn't actually send the data that it was
>   pointing to.

In other words, instead of sending the pointers, you need to send the data that the pointers point to, and the receiving process has to populate the values of its pointers itself. In your case, I'd split the send into two rounds:

- In round 1, you send `info1` and `info2` from each struct (either as an array of 2-integer vectors, or just as an array of integers). The receiving process allocates the appropriate size of `NodeItem`s, and in each one, leaves `data` uninitialized. `info1` and `info2` are filled from the received data, while `next` is determined locally (as it is originally on the sending process).
- In round 2, you create a message from all the data that your `data` pointers are pointing to. The receiving process now allocates space for each `NodeItem`, and sets the `data` pointer to the allocated address.

For the sending in round 2, you can define an `MPI_Indexed` datatype. The number of blocks is the number of `NodeItem` objects, the lengths are the sizes of each array, and the displacements can be calculated by calling `MPI_Address()` with the first element of the array (not the `data` pointer!) as input.